# Setting up TclArray in R

Tags: r, tcl, tk-toolkit

I am new to coding and I am trying to set up TclArray in R, so anytime users checks the checkbutton in GUI, TclArray will get input 0 or 1. The issues in my code occurs in value2, the code does not assign 1 or 0 each checkbutton. Also, once I value is assign, how do I assign it to other regular array?

Thanks,

[image: GUI Output Screenshot]

```
library(tcltk)

base2 = tktoplevel()
tkwm.title(base2,'Process data Input')

headers <- c("Files","Tool1","Tool2","Tool3","Tool4")
file_name_GUI <- c("SYS1","SYS2","SYS3","SYS4") #More system can be added

parameters <- tclArray()

nfrm2 = tkframe(base2)

fontSub <- tkfont.create(family="times",size=11.0, weight="bold")
fontSub2 <- tkfont.create(family="times",size=11.0)

for (i in 0:length(file_name_GUI))
{
   if(i == 0)
   {

     f2 = tkframe(nfrm2)
     value = tklabel(f2,text=headers[1], font = fontSub, width = 20,bg="gray64", relief = 'raised')
     tkgrid(value, row = i, column=0, padx =1, pady =1)

    }else
    {
     f2 = tkframe(nfrm2)
     value1 = tklabel(f2,text=file_name_GUI[i], font = fontSub2, width = 23)
     tkgrid(value1,row=i,column=0, padx = 1, pady = 1)
    }
   for (j in 1:4)
   {
     if (i == 0){
      value = tklabel(f2,text=headers[j+1], font = fontSub, width = 20,bg="gray64", relief = 'raised')
      tkgrid(value,row=i,column=j,padx=1,padx=1)
      }
     else {
       value2 = tkcheckbutton(f2, variable = .Tcl(paste("set parameters(", i, ",", j, ") 1", sep = "")), width = 23)  #Issue is here, I can't assign value to each checkbox.
       tkgrid(value2,row = i, column = j, padx = 1, pady =1)
         }
      }
     tkpack(f2,side ='top')
    }


  tkpack(nfrm2)
```